# How to get the V co-ordinate of a point in libsodium?

Tags: libsodium

The public keys ad the result of scalar multiplication in libsodium is always the U - coordinate of the point of curve25519 (RFC 7748). Is there a method in libsodium that helps to get the V coordinate from the U co-ordinate. Or is there any other library to derive the V co-ordinate?

Edit : While the problem is still unsolved , fortunately, after reworking on my use case , I realised that I do not need to get V co-ordinate for the next primitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve equation is v^2 = u^3 + 486662u^2 + u.

So, finding v just means solving the equation.

v = sqrt(u^3 + 486662u^2 + u)

Comment: The equation is v^2 = u^3 + 486662u^2 + u mod p . Not sure How to take out the sqrt then.

Comment: Though I have realized that I don't need the V coordinate in further primitives. Thanks mate @Frank Dennis

Comment: The Tonelli-Shanks algorithm can be used to compute the modular square root. But if you are using a bignum library that does modular arithmetic, it probably implements this operation already.